# How to load three-orbitcontrols with import syntax?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

Has anyone tried using the `OrbitControls` function with `ReactJS`?
Here is the sample code I wrote:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'tachyons';
import * as THREE from 'react';
import OrbitControls from 'three-orbitcontrols';
class App extends Component {
render() {
...
//Controls
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
controls.dampingFactor = 0.25
controls.enableZoom = false
```

It returns the following error:

> ./node_modules/three-orbitcontrols/OrbitControls.js 1054:70-89 "export
> 'OrbitControls' (imported as 'THREE') was not found in 'three'

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I don't think you got to the 3d object motion part. But i'm not sure what exactly is the problem here. It probably has something to do with the module that you're using.

Comment: This line looks not correct: `import * as THREE from 'react';`

Comment: All other functions from the THREE module are working fine except for the OrbitControls one. I am trying out different approaches. When I get a solution I will post it here, in case someone else needs help with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that when you import THREE, it is not globally scoped which is what the 'three-orbitcontrols' module relies on.

You could use this module instead - 'three-orbit-controls' (https://www.npmjs.com/package/three-orbit-controls)

and import it like so:

`const OrbitControls = require('three-orbit-controls')(THREE);`

Usage of orbital controls is the same as you have now but with this, an instance of THREE is being passed to the Orbit Controls module.

---

EDIT - 2020

Although the above answer was useful when the question was first asked, @Marquizzo rightly pointed out this is no longer the case.

Orbit Controls is now packaged with three.js and there's no need to use `require()`, when you should use the `import` statement.

Please refer to this answer now - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55929101/8837901

Comment: Even though this is the accepted answer, it's very outdated. The suggested library hasn't been maintained in 4 years, and `require()` is no longer useful now that JavaScript allows module `import`s.

Comment: Yes, well the answer is 2 years old and like most things in tech, hasn't stood the test of time. I'm sure you've found a better and up-to-date solution, so please feel free to share with the community, rather than criticise :)

Comment: Sorry to criticize, I hope you don't take it personally. It's just that this [gets asked all the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64654114/orbit-controls-not-working-in-three-js-react-native), and I've pointed several people to this question. I want new visitors to know that the answer below yours uses the recommended `import` statement, and there's no reason to use `require()` or `three-orbit-controls`, since it's natively included with Three.js.

Comment: Not all, I'm glad there's people still looking and can point people to the most updated information. I would answer this question completely differently than I did 2years ago too. I'll edit my answer and push people to the latest information. Thanks :)

Answer (score 37):

There is also an option to import OrbitControls directly from "three" package like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as THREE from 'three';
import {OrbitControls} from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";
```

and use it in the app without any issues:

```
this.controls = new OrbitControls(camera, domElement);
```

`domElement` has to be passed as second argument in latest builds of Three.js. React ref can be used for it.

Here is a live demo with latest React and Three.js https://codesandbox.io/s/github/supromikali/react-three-demo

Comment: in case you are unhappy with an answer, please, leave a comment so that I could improve

Comment: Thanks! As @mikael-lepistö also comments this is the official approach: https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Import-via-modules

Comment: Thanks this is way better than adding another package

Comment: I had to do `OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);` No idea why

Comment: @sabithpocker In the latest builds of Three.js passing domElement as a second argument is a must (previously default mount point was body of the page), thanks for commenting about that

Comment: Just what i was looking for .. Thanks !

Answer (score 6):

**Update 2020:**

`three.js` now exports `OrbitControls` as a module by default, and as others have pointed out, it can be used as follows:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';
```

---

**Original Answer:**

There is an npm package that you can use: **Orbit Controls ES6**

Link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/orbit-controls-es6

Installation:

```
npm i orbit-controls-es6 --save
```

Usage:

```
import OrbitControls from 'orbit-controls-es6';

const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

Answer (score 3):

I just did it like this when using parcel bundler:

app.js:

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";

// the rest of the example from threejs web page 
// https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/misc_controls_orbit.html
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Parcel threejs example</title>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test-threejs-with-parcel",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Threejs with parcel test",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.10.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "three": "^0.109.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to have `type="module"` in your `script` tag.

Comment: @NijatMursali it was not needed 3 years ago when using Parcel to bundle everything together (or not sure if newer versions of Parcel requires that)

Answer (score 2):

I have to go with Anurag with this one. First i had `three-orbit-controls` installed which danlong suggested, but i ended up having issues with require not being defined when trying to start the WebClient.

After that i switched to `orbit-controls-es6` and everything worked just fine.